# Regular Expression to find the job id in a string

Tags: php, regex

Please could someone help me, i will be forever appreciative.

I'm trying to create a regular expression which will extract 797 from "Your job 797 ("job_name") has been submitted"

or "Your Job 9212 ("another_job_name") has been submitted" etc.

Any ideas? Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are there any special conditions about grabbing the number?

To grab the first number, just use `/\d+/` with [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match).

```
if (preg_match('/\d+/', $subject, $match)) {
    $job_id = (int) $match[0];
}
```

Otherwise you could do something like the following which searches for a number preceeded by "job" (case-insensitive).

```
if (preg_match('/job (\d+)/i', $subject, $match)) {
    $job_id = (int) $match[1];
}
```

<sup>(There are better alternatves for this regex, but best to keep things simple at first.)</sup>

---

Another option would be to move away from regular expressions into more basic parsing of a string:

```
sscanf($subject, 'Your Job %d ("%[^"]")', $job_id, $job_title);
// use $job_id and $job_title however you like
```

Of course, similar could be done with `preg_match` but it's good to offer alternatives.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you! :-)

Out of interest, how would i extract the job name too? 

thank you so much :-)

Comment: @Jamie, see my update (below the horizontal rule) as well as Amarghosh's. P.S. you never answered my question.

Comment: using the regex /\(\"(.*?)\"\)/ would match the job name

Comment: @salathe, my apologies - which is quicker, using sscanf or using a regex match? 

"Are there any special conditions about grabbing the number?" Nopes, the number will only go from 1-99999. The message will always be in the same format.

EDIT: Although, the message could change if the executed command returns an exit status of -1, but the regex wouldn't match so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: sscanf would probably be quicker, but if the speed difference is a concern you should have mentioned that earlier.  The regex is simple (even for the ones offered which match the job name) so I wouldn't expect it to be "slow" at all.

Comment: It's not a concern, i was just curious. Thanks very much for the answer/comments.

Answer (score 2):

If the rest of the string is guaranteed to be same, a simple `\d+` would suffice.

Otherwise, use `Your job (\d+)` and read the first captured group.

```
preg_match("/Your job (\d+)/", $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1]; //prints the id.
```

Edit: modified to get job name

```
preg_match("/Your job (\d+) \("(.+?)"\)/", $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1]; //prints the id.
echo $matches[2]; //prints the job name.
```